# Recycleview Click and Child View Click

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using recycler view for products. I want to display product description on recycler item click.

I also put a button and checkbox(favorite) on recyclerview row.

Now i required to get click event of all, means i want recyclerview item click and child control click.

My layout is look like this :

[image]

RecyclerView Touch event

```
productRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
                    final int action = e.getAction();
                    final int actionMasked = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
                    if (actionMasked == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        return false;
                    } else if (actionMasked == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                        HomeActivity.productclicked = (productDatas.get
                                (2));
                        HomeActivity.loadView(new SingleProductFragment(), "SingleProduct");
                        return false; //intercepted by the viewgroup and passed down to child
                    }
                    return false;

                }

                @Override
                public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

                }
            });
```

In Adapter Add to Cart Button click

```
viewHolder.cart_action.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    UserCart.addProductToCart(Integer.parseInt(view.getTag().toString()));
                    HomeActivity.increaseCartCount();
                }
            });
```

If i didn't implement touchlistener on recyclerview then every button will work else it didn't work.

**Basically i want to know how to implement click on recyclerview item and its child**

**For information i also using Scroll Listener over RecyclerView. But i thought it didn't affect to click events**

My Adapter Class

```
package net.techdesire.swarnasikha.adapter_package;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.common.soloader.SoLoaderShim;
import com.facebook.common.util.UriUtil;
import com.facebook.drawee.backends.pipeline.Fresco;
import com.facebook.drawee.generic.GenericDraweeHierarchy;
import com.facebook.drawee.generic.GenericDraweeHierarchyBuilder;
import com.facebook.drawee.interfaces.DraweeController;
import com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView;

import net.techdesire.swarnasikha.R;
import net.techdesire.swarnasikha.activity_package.HomeActivity;
import net.techdesire.swarnasikha.data_package.ProductData;
import net.techdesire.swarnasikha.data_package.UserCart;
import net.techdesire.swarnasikha.fragments_package.SingleProductFragment;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;

/**
 * Created by Naitik Kundalia on 2/28/2017.
 */
public class ProductDataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductDataAdapter
        .ProductViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<ProductData> productDataArrayList;
    private Context context;

    public ProductDataAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ProductData> countries) {
        this.context=context;
        this.productDataArrayList = countries;
    }

    @Override
    public ProductDataAdapter.ProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_product, viewGroup,
                false);
        return new ProductViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ProductViewHolder viewHolder,final int position) {
        try {
            ProductData currentProduct = productDataArrayList.get(position);
            viewHolder.product_name.setText(currentProduct.getName());

            viewHolder.product_image.setImageURI(currentProduct.getImages().get(0).getSrc());
            viewHolder.cart_action.setTag(currentProduct.getId());
            viewHolder.cart_action.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    UserCart.addProductToCart(Integer.parseInt(view.getTag().toString()));
                    HomeActivity.increaseCartCount();
                }
            });
            viewHolder.container.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    HomeActivity.productclicked=productDataArrayList.get(position);
                    HomeActivity.loadView(new SingleProductFragment(),"SingleProduct");
                }
            });
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return productDataArrayList.size();
    }



    public class ProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
        public View container;
        public TextView addedtocart;
        public TextView product_name;
        SimpleDraweeView product_image;
        Button cart_action;
        public ProductViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            container=view;
            product_name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.row_product_name_textview);
            addedtocart = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.row_added_to_cart_textview);
            product_image=(SimpleDraweeView) view.findViewById(R.id.row_product_imageview);
            cart_action=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.row_cart_action_button);
            //view.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, "View Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can set `onClickListner` on ViewHolder.itemView along with the listeners on other childView.

Comment: i tried that previously but it is not working.Please check question i put my adapter class